# How do i import imdb list files into postgresql database?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, unix, import

I am doing a school project utilizing the IMDb database (Purely educational purposes)

Unfortunately I cannot use imdbpy2sql.py as the system is Unix and doesn't seem to have python built in.

I also:

- Cannot utilize root (Apparently even attempting to run the sudo command is enough to get one in trouble, learned this the hard way).
- Have been unable to get the outdated moviedb tools to work.
- There is a 2GB storage limit on the server with a 1500 file count limit.
- Only need a subset of all the tables (IE only actors, actresses, directors, etc. though having extra data is not a huge problem).
- I only have remote access to the server.

My question (Having taken all this into account) is what would be the easiest way to import the data? I am quite literally at a stand still with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered running imdbpy2sql.py on a different machine, then dumping the SQL database and loading it into your server?

Comment: Don't even know how to do that (or that it was a possibility) I'd appreciate any further elaboration you could give on how to do that. In the mean time I shall Google around.

pg_dump so simple. I am going to test this now. Here's hoping I can get this to work!

Comment: I added an answer with the actual commands to run, let me know if you want me to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to run imdbpy2sql.py on a different machine, then dump the SQL database and load it into your server. I'm going to assume the database is called "imdbdata". After that, run this command:

```
pg_dump imdbdata > imdbdata.pgdump
```

Then, copy that file onto your server and run this command there to load the data into its database:

```
psql imdbdata < imdbdata.pgdump
```

More information can be found at the [pg_dump page in the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html).

Comment: You're fantastic Chris, just what I needed. Wish it could of spared me a week worth of trouble and writing C programs to parse the .lists to SQL statements.

I'd up vote your reply if I had the reputation.